# my d3 line chart looks weird, I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I would like to know what causes this, and I also want to insert another line to the chart, what is the right way to do that? I know how to update data, but don't know how to make multiple lines,
any help is appreciated, thank you!
D3.js is a JavaScript library for producing dynamic, interactive data visualizations in web browsers. It makes use of Scalable Vector Graphics, HTML5, and Cascading Style Sheets standards. It is the successor to the earlier Protovis framework.

```js
const data = [{
    name: "A",
    x: 10,
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    x: 22,
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    x: 33,
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    x: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "E",
    x: 21,
  },
];
//No.1 define the svg
let graphWidth = 600,
  graphHeight = 450;
let margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 85
};
let totalWidth = graphWidth + margin.left + margin.right,
  totalHeight = graphHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom;
let svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", totalWidth)
  .attr("height", totalHeight);
//No.2 define mainGraph
let mainGraph = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
//No.3 define axises
let categoriesNames = data.map((d) => d.name);
let xScale = d3
  .scalePoint()
  .domain(categoriesNames)
  .range([0, graphWidth]); // scalepoint make the axis starts with value compared with scaleBand
var yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .range([graphHeight, 0])
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, (data) => data.x)]); //* If an arrow function is simply returning a single line of code, you can omit the statement brackets and the return keyword

//No.4 set axises
mainGraph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + graphHeight + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
mainGraph.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
//No.5 make lines
var line = d3
  .line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.name);
  }) // set the x values for the line generator
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.x);
  }) // set the y values for the line generator
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX); // apply smoothing to the line

mainGraph
  .append("path")
  .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
  .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
  .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `fill: none;` and `stroke: <your line colour here>` for the `path`. Otherwise, it thinks it's a closed shape and tries to fill it in.

That is because normally, `path`s are used to draw two-dimensional shapes. Only `line`s are assumed not to have two dimensions. See also [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path)

```js
const data = [{
    name: "A",
    x: 10,
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    x: 22,
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    x: 33,
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    x: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "E",
    x: 21,
  },
];
//No.1 define the svg
let graphWidth = 600,
  graphHeight = 450;
let margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 85
};
let totalWidth = graphWidth + margin.left + margin.right,
  totalHeight = graphHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom;
let svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", totalWidth)
  .attr("height", totalHeight);
//No.2 define mainGraph
let mainGraph = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
//No.3 define axises
let categoriesNames = data.map((d) => d.name);
let xScale = d3
  .scalePoint()
  .domain(categoriesNames)
  .range([0, graphWidth]); // scalepoint make the axis starts with value compared with scaleBand
var yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .range([graphHeight, 0])
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, (data) => data.x)]); //* If an arrow function is simply returning a single line of code, you can omit the statement brackets and the return keyword

//No.4 set axises
mainGraph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + graphHeight + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
mainGraph.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
//No.5 make lines
var line = d3
  .line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.name);
  }) // set the x values for the line generator
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.x);
  }) // set the y values for the line generator
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX); // apply smoothing to the line

mainGraph
  .append("path")
  .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
  .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
  .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator
```

```css
.line {
  stroke: blue;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I also want to insert another line by updating data, I was checking a code https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_several_group.html, but it doesn't work in v6, throw error".nest is not a function", do you know how to fix that? many thanks!

Comment: There is a big difference between v4 and v6. See the release notes of [v5](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v5.0.0) and [v6](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v6.0.0), which contain the breaking changes. I recommend searching for different examples, like https://observablehq.com/, which has more v6 content

Comment: Thanks again, I will explore that website, cheers